# How to create multiple user logins for each ubuntu system

Tags: user-management, adduser, multiple-users

I have 25 systems of ubuntu and I want to create 60 login id and password for students. And any students can use any system to use system using his/her credentials.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use LDAP or similar AD services.

Comment: ... or use NFS  to mount the home partition of each student from a central machine.

Comment: @NZD `s/or/and/`, OP will probably need both

Comment: @muru. Yes, you are right. I use LDAP for authentication and Samba to mount shares (shared ones and home dir).